# Attribute Group not available in Contact Builder when creating a new Event

Tags: marketing-cloud, event, contactbuilder

I've spent a considerable amount of time today trying to work out why new Attribute Groups are not appearing in the Create New Event dialog when creating an Event in Contact Builder. I've tried clearing my browser cache, recreating the Attribute Group and everything else I can think of, but new Attribute Groups simply do not appear. Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what is the issue here. The Attribute Groups **are** available, but are not displaying in the modal dialog. It appears there is a bug in Contact Builder (at least in Chrome) where the Event Destination table does not scroll — so if you have more than six Attribute Groups, you will never be able to select them.

[image: Create New Event dialog]

The workaround is to simply use your browser inspector to increase the `height` property of the `destination-placeholder` CSS class to increase the table height. I hope this saves someone the few hours that I lost today trying to debug this. Better still, I hope this bug is fixed in a future release...

Comment: I have notified our development team of this issue.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm told this is fixed and awaiting the next release.